# Python: Can I record the time corresponding to my results?

Tags: python, time, position

I have set up a torsion pendulum such that a computer mouse records its position while it rotates. My program opens a window in which, when the mouse moves within it, the x and y coordinates are recorded.

The only problem is that this gives me a graph of position against position, but I would like position against time so that I roughly get a dampened simple harmonic oscillator type of graph where I can measure the time period between oscillations.

Is there any way to do this?

My code is simply

```
from Tkinter import *

def printMotionEvents(event):
    #print "mouse coords: %i x %i" % (event.x, event.y)
    print  event.x, event.y

t = Tk()
t.bind('<Motion>', printMotionEvents)
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: I have added my code. I don't really know how to make it more specific, I just want to be able to record real time for as long as the mouse is recording results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) to get the current time, and record the samples together with the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There exist numerous methods to get the current time. Some of the concerns that come up are:

1. Resilience to differences in time zone. The solution may be to use UTC time. Not using UTC may sometimes be a concern during the switchover to or from Daylight Savings.
2. Resilience to NTP adjustments if crude NTP adjustments may hamper the application. On the other hand, the absence of refined NTP adjustments may hamper the application too.
3. Resilience to numerical overflows. These may have to be detected, especially if the range is insufficient for the application.
4. Compatibility with your version of Python, your operating system type, and kernel version.

You may wish to examine the `time` and `datetime` modules to find which method works best for you.

This answer is in the *community wiki* to permit users to freely improve it.